# Integrating Hibernate search With Spring

Tags: hibernate, full-text-search, hibernate-search

Can any one help me in integrating Hibernate search for folder searching.
With configuration setting i tried for annotation based where as i have to search
the folders containing pdf files.
It will be helpful if any reference is available.